# Word for "something that looks man-made/ fabricated/ artificial"

Tags: synonyms, terminology

I am writing about how the structure of a protein looks similar to previously lab-made proteins. But the subject of my work is of uncertain origin. So I am looking for a word that allows me to say something like:
The ________ structure of the *name_undecided* protein, leads me to think...

Comment: You could use *apparently* for "looks": "apparently man-made", "apparently fabricated", "apparently artifical". There may be a single word which is better than those, though.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks! It's not simply an issue of a single word, although that would be preferable. I do want to make the implication that similar proteins have in the past been synthesized in the lab as original chemicals that don't exist in nature...

Comment: Synthetic protein

Comment: Maybe "artificial-looking"

Comment: You could refer to a specific synthetic protein and add the suffix "-like".

Answer (score 1):

**Synthetic** or **manufactured** is now often recommended in the academic/technical literature as a replacement for the gendered **manmade**.

If you're certain that the protein was designed rather than evolved, you could use "The synthetic structure..." However, it sounds like you aren't certain. In this case, you could use

> "The **synthetic-appearing structure**..." or
>
> "The **synthetic aspects** [or **nature** or **appearance** or **configuration** or **arrangement**] of the structure..." or
>
> "The **protein characteristics, which evoke synthetic structures**..." or
>
> "The **protein structure, which appears similar to those of manufactured proteins,** ..." and so on.